# WebLogic giving NoSuchMethodError

Tags: jackson, weblogic

I'm new to WebLogic and I'm having a hard time getting my app to run in Weblogic 12.2.1. It starts up OK but then throws the following NoSuchMethodError when I load the app in the browser:

`2017-03-10 06:03:56,979 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] WARN  org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor - Processing of RmiServiceExporter remote call resulted in fatal exception: com.siemens.plm.lmd.docs.common.model.DataAccessManager.getTocData
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.addMixIn(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
    at com.siemens.plm.lmd.docs.plugin.xps47.services.Xps47CollectionMap.getTocData(Xps47CollectionMap.java:285) ~[data_services_xps47-4.1.1.jar:?]
    at com.siemens.plm.lmd.docs.plugin.xps47.HelpServerServiceXps47.getTocData(HelpServerServiceXps47.java:147) ~[data_services_xps47-4.1.1.jar:?]
    at com.siemens.plm.lmd.docs.server.model.PluginDataManager.getTocData(PluginDataManager.java:87) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:78) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy371.getTocData(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:212) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:39) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiBasedExporter.invoke(RmiBasedExporter.java:73) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper.invoke(RmiInvocationWrapper.java:74) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]`

This apps has the following maven dependancies, and I have checked the dependancy tree and there are no other versions of jackson-databind being included:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is a releases application that works in Jetty and Tomcat and I recently got it working in Weblogic 12.1.3, but I get the error above when running in Weblogic 12.2.1. I did noticed that Weblogic 12.2.1 includes jackson-databind-2.4.3.jar in the C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oui\modules directory, and cant help but wonder if that version may be getting loaded rather than my 2.6.0 version? Any ideas on what could be causing this problem? Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

to use your own dependencies instead of the default ones in weblogic, you should add your dependecy preference in weblogic.xml configuration.
In WEB-INT/weblogic.xml, add these:

```
<weblogic-web-app>
<context-root>/</context-root>
<container-descriptor>
<prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.fasterxml.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

The `<package-name>com.fasterxml.*</package-name>` will tell weblogic to prefer the packaged version rather than the version pre-installed.

Hope this can help you.